# Unable to load Partial View via JQuery ActionResult call in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, razor

I am stuck in this problem for hours if not days.

I can start the ActionResult that returns PartialView("MODEL") but I am unable to render actual View into the div inside an Index cshtml page.

Here is what I am trying:

Controller:

```
...
public ActionResult Calendar()
    {
        PopulateCalendarAsync();
        return PartialView(_calendarViewModel);
    }
...
```

Index.cshtml :

```
<div id="calendarDiv" ></div>
```

script inside Index:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $.get('@Url.Action("Calendar","Home")', {}, function (result) {
        $("#calendarDiv").load("~/Home/Calendar");

    });
});
```

When Index page loads, script calls the ActionResult Calendar() with no problems.

The problem is that div is not being updated.

my Calendar.cshtml page is aside Index page in Home folder.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `result` parameter of the `$.get` request will contain the `html` output of the  calendar partial view.
Assign it to the `<div>` via `$("#calendarDiv").html(result);`

Full code:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $.get('@Url.Action("Calendar","Home")')
        .then(function (result) {
             $("#calendarDiv").html(result);
         })
        .fail(function (xhqr, status, error) {
            alert(status);
            alert(JSON.stringify(xhqr));
        })
});
```

Comment: What's the value in `result`?

Comment: I will need to check it, not sure how to do this in jquery... alert(result.ToString?)

Comment: just `alert(result)` will do.

Comment: it does not pop up

Comment: Then an error might have occurred; I updated my answer to catch any.

Comment: It worked. Thanks to ".then" modification. my version must have had error. using .then actually worked. Thank you.